# Unable to find assembly 'App_Web_ufgi5ed2, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, exception

I am trying to read some files(.dat) from my local machine in my  asp.net(vb) website which stores List object data.
There are 500 files in the folder. It all works fine but sometime it starts giving below exception on Deserialize.

> Unable to find assembly 'App_Web_ufgi5ed2, Version=0.0.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null

Below is the code i am using.

```
 Try
        Dim files() As String = IO.Directory.GetFiles("c:\Data")
        Dim data As String = String.Empty
        For Each datafile As String In files
            Dim objTemp As Object
            Using stream As FileStream = File.OpenRead(datafile)
                objTemp = formatter.Deserialize(stream)
                Dim match As MyPerson = TryCast(Afis.Identify(probe, objTemp).FirstOrDefault(), MyPerson)
                If match Is Nothing Then
                    Continue For
                Else
                    Response.Write("Name:- " & match.Name)
                    Exit For
                End If
            End Using
        Next
    Catch ex As Exception
    End Try
```

Anyone have idea about this exception?

Comment: And have you looked to see whether that assembly is present? Is it present in your development environment? Please read error messages and do the logical things first, before posting here, and then provide us with the relevant information.  If the error message says that something can't be found, surely it's logical and obvious to try to find it.

Comment: As i mentioned in my post, This exception occurs sometimes only. Rest of the time all this works fine.